# What is the process for testing and building phonegap/cordova apps intended for blackberry using ripple

Tags: blackberry, cordova, ripple

I'm using ripple + cordova to create apps for android and blackberry (os 6 and 7) and everything works fine - as long as I select apache cordova as the platform. However, in order to build and test on a blackberry (simulator or device), I need to go into ripple's webworks mode. This is where the problem lies.

Ripple doesn't fire the deviceready event in this mode, neither does the compiled app. I even moved the www folder of cordova's sample app for blackberry and same thing happens. No deviceready event fired. Instead, ripple is firing another event:

webworks.handset :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.).

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct process? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed that the webworks and cordova modes of ripple are two separate entities and are in no way connected. The actual process involves using the command line/bbwp commands as specified in the cordova getting started guide for blackberry.